# Grouping nodes in XSLT based on a variable information

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a problem figuring a way to group the amount. I need to make two approaches.

-I-. First approach refers to the situation when i don't have multiple Expenses.
  (This is done). The input xml information.

```
        <ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill>
          <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
              <AFGSubCategory>Rental Expense</AFGSubCategory>
              <Amount>2000</Amount>
              <Frequency>Quarterly</Frequency>
           </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

          <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
                <AFGSubCategory>Child Maintenance Paid</AFGSubCategory>
                <Amount>1000</Amount>
                <Frequency>4 Weekly</Frequency>                    
          </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

         </ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill>
```

I'm using this xslt code:

```
<xsl:template match="ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill/AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses
    [AFGSubCategory = ('Child Maintenance Paid', 'Rental Expense')]" mode="OtherCommitment">

    <OtherCommitment 
        UniqueID="{fn:UniqueID(Id)}">

        <xsl:attribute name="Amount">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="Amount"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="Frequency" select="fn:IncomeFrequency(Frequency)"/>

        <xsl:attribute name="Category">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="AFGSubCategory = 'Child Maintenance Paid'">Child Maintenance</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="AFGSubCategory = 'Rental Expense'">Rent</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>

    </OtherCommitment>
```

To calculate the Amount i'm using the following template:

```
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="Amount">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = '4 Weekly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="(Amount * 13) div 12"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = 'Quarterly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="Amount * 4"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

For the Frequency i'm using:

```
<xsl:function name="fn:IncomeFrequency">
    <xsl:param name="Frequency"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Frequency = '4 Weekly'">Monthly</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Frequency = 'Annually'">Yearly</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Frequency = 'Quarterly'">Yearly</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Frequency != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Frequency"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Frequency/../AFGAnnualAmount != ''">Yearly</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

This is the Output which for this situation is correct:

```
         <OtherCommitment Amount="8000" Frequency="Yearly" 
              Category="Rent">
         </OtherCommitment>
         <OtherCommitment Amount="1083.3333333333333"
                            Frequency="Monthly"
                            Category="Child Maintenance">
         </OtherCommitment>
```

-II- The second situation is when i have more then one SubCategory with the same name and i need to tranform the frequency in a 'Monthly' value.
Example of input:

```
       <ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill>
          <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
              <AFGSubCategory>Rental Expense</AFGSubCategory>
              <Amount>2000</Amount>
              <Frequency>Quarterly</Frequency>
           </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

           <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
              <AFGSubCategory>Rental Expense</AFGSubCategory>
              <Amount>1000</Amount>
              <Frequency>Mounthly</Frequency>
           </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

          <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
                <AFGSubCategory>Child Maintenance Paid</AFGSubCategory>
                <Amount>1000</Amount>
                <Frequency>4 Weekly</Frequency>                    
          </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

         </ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill>
```

The Output needs to become.

```
     <OtherCommitment Amount="1666.6666666666667" Frequency="Monthly" 
          Category="Rent">
     </OtherCommitment>
    <!-- This will keep the first approach because is only one 'Child Maintenance'--> 
    <OtherCommitment Amount="1083.3333333333333"
                        Frequency="Monthly"
                        Category="Child Maintenance">
     </OtherCommitment>
```

For calculating the Amount i need to use in this case probably:

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="AmountMonthly">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = 'Weekly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:remove-scientific-notation((Amount * 52) div 12)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = 'Fortnightly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:remove-scientific-notation((Amount * 26) div 12)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = '4 Weekly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:remove-scientific-notation((Amount * 13) div 12)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = 'Monthly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = 'Quarterly'">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:remove-scientific-notation((Amount * 4) div 12)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Frequency = 'Annually'">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:remove-scientific-notation(Amount div 12)"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But i can't figuring out, how to sum the expenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged that as XSLT 2.0 so of course to group by the category use `xsl:for-each-group group-by`. I have a small example to only process the amount, I hope you can integrate it in your existing code:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">


    <xsl:function name="mf:monthlyAmount" as="xs:decimal">
        <xsl:param name="amountEl" as="element(AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="amount" as="xs:decimal" select="xs:decimal($amountEl/Amount)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="if ($amountEl/Frequency = 'Weekly')
                              then $amount * 52 div 12
                              else if ($amountEl/Frequency = 'Quarterly')
                              then $amount * 4 div 12
                              else if ($amountEl/Frequency = 'Monthly')
                              then $amount
                              else 0"/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses" group-by="AFGSubCategory">
            <OtherCommitment Amount="{sum(for $item in current-group() return mf:monthlyAmount($item))}"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Transforms

```
<ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill>
          <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
              <AFGSubCategory>Rental Expense</AFGSubCategory>
              <Amount>2000</Amount>
              <Frequency>Quarterly</Frequency>
           </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

           <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
              <AFGSubCategory>Rental Expense</AFGSubCategory>
              <Amount>1000</Amount>
              <Frequency>Monthly</Frequency>
           </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

          <AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>
                <AFGSubCategory>Child Maintenance Paid</AFGSubCategory>
                <Amount>1000</Amount>
                <Frequency>4 Weekly</Frequency>                    
          </AFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpenses>

         </ListOfAFGFINSApplicationIncomeandExpensesFormFill>
```

into

```
<OtherCommitment Amount="1666.666666666666666667"/><OtherCommitment Amount="0"/>
```

so I think for the first group the computation is correct, you will need to add the other attributes and you need to add the other computations for the various amount types.

Example is online at http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvq.

Comment: i've fixed the issue using like you said xsl:for-each-group group-by. Thank you for your reply.